# Godot: Instancing one label only

Tags: godot

How do I instance a particular label from a scenetree without instancing all the scene?

I tried instancing all the scene but it does not work

Comment: "does not work" is not a good way to describe a problem. As per instancing a single label, you can make a scene of a single label. And, of course, you could instead use `Label.new()` and sets the properties. Edit: ah, and remember to add the label to the scene tree.

Comment: But my label is part of an endgame screen together with other labels and containers. It contains " You finished the game in + str(Game.seconds) + " seconds" .  Can I just instance this one particular label?

Comment: You can make a scene that just that label and use it in both places.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. Doesnt that label require to be under my Game scenetree so that I can use Game.seconds?

Comment: If to work it needs to be in the scene tree. Then instance it and add it to the scene tree. I don't know what `Game.seconds` is. (I only know what you have told here). My guess is that `Game` is an Autoload, shame on me for taking an educated guess. If it is something specific of the scene that currently owns the Label, then instancing the Label without the scene -if it were possible- would not work anyway. Refactor your code, so that is not the case. It is not a good idea to depend on a node that is not a child and is not an Autoload. Call down, signal up. So you don't run into this problem.

Comment: If you are going to instance something, it has to be an scene, not part of a scene. If you need the same thing in two scene (say SceneA, and SceneB), you make that part a new scene (say SceneC) and use it both scenes (SceneA, and SceneB). Hopefully that makes sense.